# Bootstrap CSS lining up text with heading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two columns (col-md-4 and col-md-8) col-md-4 has a an h1 element and col-md-8 has a paragraph element. What I am trying to do is have both element align in the middle, I have tried to use a line-height, but on small screens sometimes the text is on two lines and there is a massive spacing, so my question is how do I align both elements in the middle regardless if there is 1, 2 or 3 lines in the paragraph element.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h1>Heading One</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non risus nibh. Suspendisse vehi.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the fabulous matchHeight JQuery plugin (available to download here: https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height) to ensure both parent containers are the same height. Then you can use `display:flex; align-items:center;` to center the content of each parent container vertically. You can find out more about flexbox here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to those columns, and add `flexbox` properties to that class. You'll need to set a `min-width` to visualise the centering.

Then use media queries to remove this.

This snippet is best viewed fullscreen..

```css
.col-flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 200px !important;
}

.col-flex h1
.col-flex p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-flex">
                    <h1>Heading One</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-flex">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non risus nibh. Suspendisse vehi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non risus nibh. Suspendisse vehi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non risus nibh. Suspendisse vehi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non risus nibh. Suspendisse vehi.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

U have 2 options to align them in the middle:
 1. [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)
 2. [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/display): table/table-cell

with table cell, as long as you're using bootstrap u also have to play a bit with float ;)

[here](http://daker.me/2014/04/4-css-tricks-for-vertical-alignment.html) you'l find examples for 4 different ways to align vertically